# Java - Try/catch method issue

Tags: java, methods, try-catch

I have a problem trying to use the try/catch in my code. Whenever i try and return the result; i get the error "cannot resolve symbol 'result'". Here is my code.

```
public Object remove(int index) {
    try{
        Object result = this.get(index);
        for (int k = index; k < size-1; k++) items[k] = items[k + 1];
        items[size] = null;
        size--;
        return result;
     }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("Exception occurred in 'remove' method.");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined result variable within try block. if you declare variable within `{}` braces then that variable will be avialble for use within those braces only and it wont be available to outside world.

So to resolve the issue, you do something like:

```
Object result = null;
try {
   ....
} catch ... {
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` is initialized inside the try block. The try/catch blocks work similarly to if/else in that you can not see an object initialized in the other block. You can work around this by initializing `result` before the `try`.

```
public Object remove(int index) {
  Object result;
  try{
    result = this.get(index);
    for (int k = index; k < size-1; k++) items[k] = items[k + 1];
    items[size] = null;
    size--;
    return result;
  }
  catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    System.out.println("Exception occurred in 'remove' method.");
    return result;
  }
}
```

You probably shouldn't have to catch the out of bounds exception at all how ever. Asuming `items` is an array, you can use `items.length` in your for loop to prever going out of bounds.